# Run files terminating in "Spec" as tests

Tags: maven

Whenever I run `mvn test` in my Maven project, only the test files ending in `Test` are executed.

However, all my test files in the current project are ending in `Spec` and I don't want to change their names.

So how can I configure maven to execute files ending in `Spec` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the [Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin) will automatically include files respecting these patterns:

- ***/Test*.java*
- ***/*Test.java*
- ***/*TestCase.java*

To add more patterns, and specifically yours, just configure the plugin in the following way:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See also the [complete documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) about this kind of configuration.